# Split function not creating array()

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've worked this code over a few times, but I always seem to have a problem with the `Split` statement passing my array. Here's a piece of code that's not working and I can't figure out why

```
Private Sub parseCSV()
'Parse "Notes" column and return Moods/Keywords to their apropriate cells

    Dim CSV As String
    Dim fullArray() As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim Keywords As String
    Dim Moods As String

    Dim i As Long

    lRow = ActiveSheet().Range("BL" & ActiveSheet().Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lRow

        CSV = ActiveSheet.Range("BL" & i)
        fullArray() = Split(CSV, Chr(10))

        ActiveSheet.Range("CE" & i).Value = fullArray(3)
        ActiveSheet.Range("CD" & i).Value = fullArray(2)

    Next i

End Sub
```

It gives an Err-9, value out of range. It's so weird. I've tested it a bunch of different ways and this is what I've found.

It will return the 1st piece of data in the array. I can change my delimiter to any thing i want and get exactly what I would expect in the first place of the array returned, if I change my code to fullArray(). I've also tried using Application.Index(fullArray, 1, 2), no dice. I've tried using various combination of array coordinates and variant/string combos. Nothing. Please help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is an example of what is contained in the cell being split;

```
To License Contact, licensing@primarywavemusic.com, 212.661.6990/310.247.8630
Go, White, Know
Happy, Rock, Upbeat, Catchy
```

Comment: Most likely one of the cells in BL does not contain `Chr(10)` (**vbLf**) and so the array has length of 1 (`UBound` is 0). You need to ensure the `UBound(fullArray) > 2` before using 3.

Comment: No it defiantly registers a Chr(10) Read the last part of my question. I can determine that it is finding the delimiter by changing it. If i use Chr(10) as my delimiter it returns everything up to the delimiter. If I use a false character such as a "%" (which is no in the cell) it will return the whole cell to me. Ergo, `Split` must be recognizing the Chr(10) in the cell. Its a good thought though. I just already tested it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test the `UBound` first to verify there are actually 3 lines. A `UBound(fullArray)` of 2 indicates three lines. This is an example of a zero based array. The third line ends up in `fullArray(2)`.

If your input is three lines long you can get the split using:

```
fullArray(0)
fullArray(1)
fullArray(2)
```

Here is your adjusted code:

```
For i = 3 To lRow

    If UBound(fullArray) >= 2 Then
        CSV = ActiveSheet.Range("BL" & i)
        fullArray() = Split(CSV, Chr(10))

        ActiveSheet.Range("CE" & i).Value = fullArray(2) 'enter third line
        ActiveSheet.Range("CD" & i).Value = fullArray(1) 'enter second line
    Else
        'this will output the cell address of any cell that
        'doesn't have 3 lines within the cell
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("BL" & i).Address
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Well that was enlightening, but not sure what to do now. It fails the `If` statement and returns what is in the original cell to be `Split`to the "Immediate Window". I've edited the original question to show an example of what's being contained in the cell i'm trying to `Split`. By the `If` statement code you provided i'm not sure what i should expect in the immediate window upon failure. It should be the last value of the array `fullArray` a space and then original value to compare to right?

Comment: @JamieMarshall what is the expected result? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for your three line example; That was helpful and I hope my edited answer is too.

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone I think we're getting somewhere. Better than a screenshot, I posted a video [HERE](http://youtu.be/ue-PueMQ9Jk) that shows my code, my sheet, and the immediate window.

Comment: Got it. There was an error being thrown that caused the Array to fail. Using an `If` statement like the one posted on this answer and leaving the `Else` section bank skipped the error and made the code work. Thanks again to all.